# The fundamental group of a point is $1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, triangulation

> Show that the fundamental group of the point space $p$ is given as $\pi(p, w_0)=1$ where $w_0$ is the base point

This is probably somewhat trivial, but I am looking for a proof. I am familiar with computing fundamental groups by triangulating simplicial complexes. In this case the triangulation is itself with no generators, so it makes sense that the fundamental group is trivial

I am looking for an alternative, concrete proof

Thanks!

Comment: Ask yourself: what paths are there in the space $p$?

Comment: In fact there is only one map from $I$ to a point, and the fundamental group consists of equivalence classes of such maps under homotopy.

Comment: @LeeMosher there are no paths.. unless you think of the loop back to the point. Is this the trivial loop which is accounted for by  $\pi=1$?

Comment: A path is simply a continuous function $[0,1] \mapsto p$. Why do you say there are no paths?

Comment: because a point has no length, and paths have a length.. so do we consider the paths that are loops?

Comment: @thinker A path is just a continuous map from a subset of the real line into a topological space. You need extra data to even define the notion of "length".

Comment: The important thing here is that you not let your intuitive notion of "path" over-ride the mathematical definition of "path" that is used in defining the fundamental group. If your intuition is betraying you into mis-understanding the definition of fundamental group, fix your intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one possible map from $[0, 1]$ to $p$, so there cannot be any two paths that are different, much less not even homotopic. Hence the fundamental group cannot have more than one element, so it is the trivial group.

Comment: thanks. and all fundamental groups must contain the trivial element?

Comment: Yes. Any fundamental group $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ contains at least the class of the trivial path $t \mapsto x_0$.

Comment: @thinker: For a greater reason, the first homotopy group is a $\textbf{group}$ most importantly.